# ngx-chips: unable to show auto complete items

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

In Angular, I want to show the items (genreName) in autocomplete. In the `.html` I wrote the following:

```
 <tag-input [ngModel]="genre" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true">
            <tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="false"
                                [autocompleteItems]="responseRawGenreList">
            </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

In the `.ts` file, I wrote the following codes:

```
this.commonService.getAllGenre(this.userToken).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.responseRawGenreList = data.data;
  console.log(this.responseRawGenreList)
});
```

The above code consoling the result as below:

```
[0 … 99]
0: {genreId: 4, genreName: "Action", genreDescription: "", status: "ONE"}
1: {genreId: 5, genreName: "Action", genreDescription: "", status: "ONE"}
2: {genreId: 6, genreName: "Action", genreDescription: "", status: "ONE"}
3: {genreId: 7, genreName: "ऐक्शन", genreDescription: "", status: "ONE"}
```

When I enter something into the 'input tag' on browser, it shows me the below error:

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>       at TagInputDropdown.matchingFn (ngx-chips.js:207)
>       at ngx-chips.js:1216
>       at Array.filter ()
>       at TagInputDropdown.getMatchingItems (ngx-chips.js:1208)
>       at SafeSubscriber.TagInputDropdown.show [as _next] (ngx-chips.js:1011)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
>       at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
>       at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>       at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `[identifyBy]` and `[displayBy]` and pass the property name.

You can either set:

```
identifyByProperty = 'genreId';

[identifyBy]="identifyByProperty"
```

or,

```
identifyBy="genreId"
```

Try like this:

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="genre" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true">
    <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteObservable]="requestAutocompleteItems" displayBy="genreName"
        identifyBy="genreId">
    </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example-b13btq)**

Comment: >Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TagInputComponent]:

Comment: `<tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteObservable]="responseRawGenreList" [displayBy]="genreName"
            [identifyBy]="genreId" >
        </tag-input-dropdown>`

Comment: Change this property as follow and try   [identifyBy]="'genreId'" [displayBy]="'genreName'"

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara Try like this: `displayBy="genreName"
        identifyBy="genreId"`. Check the demo I shared

Comment: Thats fine,! however, how can i validate the ngx-chips (input tag) on form submission? Means I want to check whether the input tag is empty or not?

Comment: You have to manually do it on model change _ Adrita Sharma - Chandannagar :D